# Clone is invalid syntax, downloading github projects

Tags: python, github

So, I was trying to download sherlock-project on github, heres the link: https://github.com/sherlock-project/sherlock on the page it says that to download it I just have to write this in console: `git clone https://github.com/sherlock-project/sherlock.git` unfortunately the command prompt shows me this issue: https://prnt.sc/vmtfj5 . And yes, I do have git downloaded ( https://prnt.sc/vmtgel ) but it still doesn't lets me to clone the repository. My question is, how to fix that?

P.S. This is first day I opened python in my life so do not expect anything smart from me, oh and by the way, thank you for spending your time on me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call git clone from the command line, not inside python. If you are still inside python, press ctrl+D or call exit(), then call the git clone command.

Comment: How to call it?

Comment: just like you did, type and press enter