# Error when installing python package from GitHub

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, syntax-error

I want to install a package from GitHub and I am following a guide from https://worldbank.github.io/connectivity_mapping/facebook_nbs/web_interface.html to do so. I copied and pasted the code but I keep getting this error:

```
git clone https://github.com/joaopalotti/pySocialWatcher 
File "<ipython-input-1-cee23b0d65fc>", line 1
    git clone https://github.com/joaopalotti/pySocialWatcher
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Does anyone know what the problem is? I am doing this in jupyter notebook and I am very new to Python. Do I need to run any lines of code before this one to make it work?

Comment: `git clone <link>` is **not** Python syntax, it's a shell command you need to run _outside_ the Python interpreter.

Comment: Open Command prompt and type in that command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clone is invalid syntax, downloading github projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64929744/clone-is-invalid-syntax-downloading-github-projects)

Answer (score 0):

> In order to install PySocialWatcher in your system, we can use the following commands:

That means command line, where `git` and `python` are installed and in your `$PATH`.

Comment: For example bash (Linux) or PowerShell (Windows)

Comment: @Leo Yes, even a regular CMD on Windows works.